# Vendor class isn't auto loaded properly

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm wanting to use the [mpdf](http://mpdf1.com/) library with symfony1.4

I have downloaded the library in to `lib/vendor/mPDF` and I' have updated my `autoload.yml` file in `config/autoload.yml` to include the following:

```
mPDF:
  name:       mPDF
  path:       %SF_LIB_DIR%/vendor/mPDF
  recursive:  on
```

When I then instantiate the mPDF class,

```
$mdpf = new mPDF();
```

I get the following:

```
Fatal Error: Class 'mPDF' not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your autoload file should be like this :

```
autoload:
  mPDF:
    path:      %SF_LIB_DIR%/vendor/mPDF
```

You must have a first level with `autoload`.

By the way, in your case, you just need to load one file, so you don't have to define the `recursive:  on` and the `name`.

Comment: I believe `mPDF` uses more than one file. Should the autoloader not load `mPDF` recursively?

Comment: Of course, mPDF use more than one file, but other files are *loaded* using a `require_once` inside the main mPDF.php file. So they don't need to be autoloaded.